# Is there a way to disable any use of cookies for my website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, web-applications

I am trying to improve the security on a web application created in `react`.

I am completely sure that functionality wise there are no cookies used, but I keep on getting cookies when I go to the page. When I check Application tab in developer's tool I can see that my website is putting a cookie there.

Is there a general way to prevent my app from using/storing any cookies at all?

Disclaimer: There are no references to setting cookies in the project.

Comment: Great, -1 without a comment. +1 from me for it. Let me close it then

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to any cookie related event with [cookies.onChanged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged), so you can clear any cookie created